# Multiple postfix instances one host

Tags: email, smtp, postfix

I have a server on which i need to add setup a second postfix configuration to send e-mail (doesn't have to receive) that's being sent in from a PHP web application that's hosted on the server aswell. I need a second instance because a different site needs to send e-mails with a different certificate then the first set up. However i'm running into an issue and could use some help setting this up.

I've already copied the first instance and made a new one out of it:

```
[root@THEP01VMA01 /]# ls -l /etc/ | grep postfix
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root           root   4096 Nov 10 07:08 postfix
drwxr-xr-x   3 root           root   4096 Nov 17 04:15 postfix-zorgmail
```

And i've added a second spool aswell:

```
[root@THEP01VMA01 /]# ls -l /var/spool/ | grep postfix
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root   root   4096 Nov  5 02:51 postfix
drwxr-xr-x  16 root   root   4096 Nov  6 08:08 postfix-zorgmail
```

And i've added the following in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
alternate_config_directories = /etc/postfix-zorgmail
```

I've also added a second IP adress to the server and bound an A-record to it:

[root@THEP01VMA01 /]# cat /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

134.xx.xx.xxx     postfix1.setup.fqdn serverhostname
134.xx.xx.xxx     postfix2.setup.fqdn
```

(kinda censored the ip adress and the hostnames/a-records)

And then in my /etc/postfix-zorgmail/main.cf i've added the following lines:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-zorgmail
myhostname = postfix2.setup.fqdn
inet_interfaces = 134.xx.xx.xxx
```

(the ip adress being the second IP)

However when i try to mail from the mail client i get the errors:

```
*17-11-14 10:17:01 log [info] ^M
<b>TRIGGER_NOTICE</b> [1024] Error in sending mail: unable to connect to smtp server ssl://postfix2.setup.fqdn:465<br />^M
^M

17-11-14 10:32:53 log [info] ^M
<b>TRIGGER_NOTICE</b> [1024] Error in sending mail: unable to connect to smtp server ssl://134.xx.xx.xxx:465<br />^M*
```

I've tried connecting with the ip adress and the a-record.
I'm certrain that ports 465 (and 25) are open and it should be able to connect.
I'll bet that i'm forgetting to set up something for this multiple postfix set up but i'm unclear as to what. Anyone have any ideas or any experience with a set up like this ?
Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.